# для чего нужны .env файлы в react

Tags: reactjs

я видел что в них хранят API KEY,урлы и все такое но как то не магу понять смысл чем они лучше обычных констант в js да и вообще зачем и как их использовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.env файл не загружается в гит, как раз для того, чтобы если Вы складываете туда уникальные ключи - они не были доступны всему интернету. Env (environment - среда) настраивается под вашу среду разработки и используется в рамках нее.

Comment: а разница я также могу добавить в .gitignore какой то js файл  и хранить там

Comment: Можете, и никто не может Вам этого запретить :) Но принято такие вещи складывать в .env. Как и другие различные настройки среды разработки. Когда кто-то скачает Ваш репозиторий из гита, он будет знать, что параметры надо дописать в .env, и не будет искать это по куче других файлов. :)  Зачастую рядом кладут еще .env.example , с примером данных, которые нужны чтобы завести Ваше приложение.

Comment: спасибо и еше один вопрос .. допустим я слил в гит проект и кто то скачал и если мой код работает с тем что в .env то есть пути и все такое как он сможет запустить его какую инфу дает env.example?

Comment: в env.example вы пишите пример. типа. yaKey = 'ввести сюда ключ yandex...', gKey = 'ввести сюда ключ google' и т.д.. Соответственно, человек будет знать, что чтобы завести Ваше приложение ему надо завести эти ключи и ввести их в env.

Comment: все большое спасибо

Comment: Если Вам помог мой ответ - выберите, пожалуйста, мой ответ как верный. Галочка слева :)

Comment: ограничение есть по времени на выбор знаю)